# How do I delete boto3 stream before trying to open one with same name?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am using boto3 to fetch data using TwitterAPI. It opens a stream correctly the first time I run the program, but if I do a KeyboardInterupt in console and then try to run the program, I get the error:

```
botocore.errorfactory.ResourceInUseException: An error occurred 
(ResourceInUseException) when calling the CreateStream 
operation: Stream TwitterStream under account XXXXXXXXXX already exists.
```

If I manually go in and change the name of the stream, I am able to create another stream, but this is kind of a hassle.

```
client = boto3.client('kinesis',region_name="us-east-2")
response = client.create_stream(StreamName='TwitterStream',ShardCount=1)

api = TwitterAPI(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token_key, 
access_token_secret)

kinesis = boto3.client('kinesis')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream names are unique per account and region.  So you can't recreate a stream that already exists.  According to the [create_stream docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/kinesis.html#Kinesis.Client.create_stream):

> The stream name identifies the stream. The name is scoped to the AWS
>   account used by the application. It is also scoped by AWS Region. That
>   is, two streams in two different accounts can have the same name, and
>   two streams in the same account, but in two different Regions, can
>   have the same name.

You will need to check if you need to create the stream or manage the error.  Something like:

```
try:
    client = boto3.client('kinesis',region_name="us-east-2")
    response = client.create_stream(StreamName='TwitterStream',ShardCount=1)

    print('stream {} created'.format(stream_name))
except ResourceInUseException:
    print('stream {} already exists'.format(stream_name))

api = TwitterAPI(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token_key, access_token_secret)

kinesis = boto3.client('kinesis')
```

Understand that when a stream is created you will need to wait for it to become `ACTIVE` - they are not usable instantly.

Having said that, if you really want to delete it first change the code to something like:

```
try:
    client = boto3.client('kinesis',region_name="us-east-2")
    response = client.create_stream(StreamName='TwitterStream',ShardCount=1)

    print('stream {} created'.format(stream_name))
except ResourceInUseException:
    print('stream {} already exists'.format(stream_name))
    client.delete_stream(StreamName='TwitterStream')

status = 'not set'
while( status != 'ACTIVE' )
    describe_stream_response = client.describe_stream(stream_name)
    description = describe_stream_response.get('StreamDescription')
    status = description.get('StreamStatus')
    time.sleep(1)

api = TwitterAPI(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token_key, access_token_secret)

kinesis = boto3.client('kinesis')
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, really appreciate it :)